# C++ code for Priority Search Tree

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to implement a `Priority Search Tree(PST)` following this note: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs252/misc/resources/lectures/pdf/notes07.pdf. For convenience, I copied the related peuso-code here:
[image: creating PST]

and the note has also provided an example for creating a PST, I just copied the final tree here:

[image: PST_example]

The following is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <queue> 


template <typename E>
struct Point2D {
    static int used_count;
    E _x;
    E _y;
    Point2D() : _x(0), _y(0) {
        used_count++;
        std::cout << "Point2D(), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
    }
    Point2D(const E& x, const E& y) : _x(x), _y(y) {
        used_count++;
        std::cout << "Point2D(const E& x, const E& y), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
    }
    Point2D(int arr[]) : _x(arr[0]), _y(arr[1]) {
        used_count++;
        std::cout << "Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
    }
    Point2D(const Point2D& other) {  // copy constructor
        used_count++;
        std::cout << "Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
        _x = other._x;
        _y = other._y;
    }
    Point2D(Point2D& other) {  // copy constructor
        used_count++;
        std::cout << "Point2D(Point2D& other), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
        _x = other._x;
        _y = other._y;
    }
    Point2D& operator=(const Point2D& other) { // assignment operator
        _x = other._x;
        _y = other._y;
        return *this;
    }
    Point2D& operator=(Point2D& other) { // assignment operator
        _x = other._x;
        _y = other._y;
        return *this;
    }
    Point2D(Point2D&& other) {  // move constructor
        if (this != &other) {
            used_count++;
            std::cout << "Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
            _x = other._x;
            _y = other._y;
        }
    }

    virtual ~Point2D() {
        used_count--;
        std::cout << "~Point2D(), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
    }

    Point2D operator-(const Point2D& other) {
        return Point2D(_x - other._x, _y - other._y);
    }
    Point2D operator-(Point2D& other) {
        return Point2D(_x - other._x, _y - other._y);
    }
    bool operator<(const Point2D& other) {
        return (_y < other._y) || (_y == other._y && _x < other._x);
    }
};


template <typename E>
class PSTMultiset {
public:
    struct Element {
        std::string _name;
        Point2D<E> _point;

        Element(const std::string& name, int arr[])
            : _name(name), _point(arr) {}
    };

    struct ElementComparatorY {
        bool operator()(const Element& l, const Element& r) {
            return (l._point._y > r._point._y) ||
                    (l._point._y == r._point._y && l._point._x > r._point._x);
        }
    };
    struct ElementComparatorX {
        bool operator()(const Element& l, const Element& r) {
            return (l._point._x < r._point._x) ||
                    (l._point._x == r._point._x && l._point._y < r._point._y);
        }
    };

    std::multiset<Element, ElementComparatorY> _points;
    typedef typename std::multiset<Element, ElementComparatorY>::iterator Iterator;
    int _size;

    PSTMultiset(int size) : _size(size) {
        std::cout << "PSTMultiset(int size)\n";
    }
    PSTMultiset(std::string names[], E points[][2], int size)
        : PSTMultiset(size) {  // Nx2 points
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            _points.insert(Element(names[i], points[i]));
        }
        std::cout << "PSTMultiset(std::string names[], E points[][2])\n";
    }

    virtual ~PSTMultiset() {
        Clear();
        std::cout << "~PSTMultiset()\n";
    }

    void Print(const std::string& title) {
        std::cout << title << "\n";
        for (auto iter = _points.begin(); iter != _points.end(); iter++) {
            const Element& p = *iter;
            std::cout << p._name << ": (" << p._point._x << ", " << p._point._y << ")\n";
        }
    }

    class Node {
    public:
        Element _element;
        Node *_parent;
        Node *_left;
        Node *_right;

        Node(const Element& element, Node* parent)
            : _element(element),
              _parent(parent),
              _left(nullptr),
              _right(nullptr) {

        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Node* node) {
            if (node == nullptr) {
                return out;
            }

            if (node->_left != nullptr) {
                out << "L(" << node->_left->_element._name << ")_";
            }

            out << node->_element._name
                << ": (" << node->_element._point._x << ", "
                << node->_element._point._y << ")";

            if (node->_right != nullptr) {
                out << "_R(" << node->_right->_element._name << ")";
            }

            return out;
        }
    };

    Node *_root;

    Node* Build(Node* parent, std::multiset<Element, ElementComparatorY>& points) {

        if (points.size() == 0) return nullptr;
        if (points.size() == 1) {
            Node *node = new Node(*(points.begin()), parent);
            return node;
        }

        auto first = points.begin();

        std::multiset<Element, ElementComparatorX> remainPoints;
        auto iter = points.begin(); iter++;  // remove the first point (the point with greatest Y)
        for (; iter != points.end(); iter++) {
            remainPoints.insert(*iter);
        }

        auto mid_iter = remainPoints.begin();
        std::advance(mid_iter, remainPoints.size() / 2);

        std::multiset<Element, ElementComparatorY> leftPoints(remainPoints.begin(), mid_iter);
        std::multiset<Element, ElementComparatorY> rightPoints(mid_iter, remainPoints.end());

        Node *node = new Node(*first, parent);
        node->_left = Build(node, leftPoints);
        node->_right = Build(node, rightPoints);

        return node;
    }

    void Build() {
        _root = Build(nullptr, _points);
    }

    void Clear() {  // clear the tree by level-order traverse
        if (_root == nullptr) return;
        std::queue<Node*> q;
        q.push(_root);
        int height = 1;
        int levelSize = q.size();
        while (!q.empty()) {
            Node *node = q.front();

            std::cout << node << " ";

            if (node->_left != nullptr) {
                q.push(node->_left);
            }
            if (node->_right != nullptr) {
                q.push(node->_right);
            }

            delete node;

            q.pop();
            levelSize--;
            if (levelSize == 0) {
                height++;
                levelSize = q.size();

                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Height: " << height << "\n";
    }

};

template<> int Point2D<int>::used_count = 0;

int main() {
    std::string names[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
                             "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
                             "K", "M", "N"};
    int arr[][2] = {{15, 7},
                  {16, 2},
                  {12, 1},
                  {14, -1},
                  {10, -2},
                  {-1, 9},
                  {6, 4},
                  {7, 6},
                  {-2, 5},
                  {2, 3},
                  {4, 0},
                  {9, -3},
                  {1, 8}};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    PSTMultiset<int> *t = new PSTMultiset<int>(names, arr, size);

    // print the multiset 
    {
      t->Print("before"); 
    }

    // build PST
    {
      t->Build();
    }

    delete t;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
PSTMultiset(int size)
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 1
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 2
~Point2D(), used_count = 1
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 2
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 3
~Point2D(), used_count = 2
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 3
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 4
~Point2D(), used_count = 3
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 4
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 5
~Point2D(), used_count = 4
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 5
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 6
~Point2D(), used_count = 5
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 6
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 7
~Point2D(), used_count = 6
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 7
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 8
~Point2D(), used_count = 7
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 8
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 9
~Point2D(), used_count = 8
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 9
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 10
~Point2D(), used_count = 9
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 10
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 11
~Point2D(), used_count = 10
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 11
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 12
~Point2D(), used_count = 11
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 12
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 13
~Point2D(), used_count = 12
Point2D(int arr[]), used_count = 13
Point2D(Point2D&& other), used_count = 14
~Point2D(), used_count = 13
PSTMultiset(std::string names[], E points[][2])
before
F: (-1, 9)
N: (1, 8)
A: (15, 7)
H: (7, 6)
I: (-2, 5)
G: (6, 4)
J: (2, 3)
B: (16, 2)
C: (12, 1)
K: (4, 0)
D: (14, -1)
E: (10, -2)
M: (9, -3)
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 14
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 15
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 16
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 17
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 18
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 19
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 20
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 21
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 22
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 23
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 24
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 25
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 26
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 27
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 28
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 29
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 30
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 31
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 32
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 33
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 34
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 35
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 36
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 37
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 38
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 39
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 40
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 41
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 42
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 43
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 44
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 45
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 46
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 47
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 48
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 49
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 50
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 51
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 52
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 53
~Point2D(), used_count = 52
~Point2D(), used_count = 51
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 52
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 53
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 54
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 55
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 56
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 57
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 58
~Point2D(), used_count = 57
~Point2D(), used_count = 56
~Point2D(), used_count = 55
~Point2D(), used_count = 54
~Point2D(), used_count = 53
~Point2D(), used_count = 52
~Point2D(), used_count = 51
~Point2D(), used_count = 50
~Point2D(), used_count = 49
~Point2D(), used_count = 48
~Point2D(), used_count = 47
~Point2D(), used_count = 46
~Point2D(), used_count = 45
~Point2D(), used_count = 44
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 45
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 46
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 47
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 48
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 49
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 50
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 51
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 52
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 53
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 54
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 55
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 56
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 57
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 58
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 59
~Point2D(), used_count = 58
~Point2D(), used_count = 57
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 58
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 59
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 60
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 61
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 62
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 63
Point2D(const Point2D& other), used_count = 64
~Point2D(), used_count = 63
~Point2D(), used_count = 62
~Point2D(), used_count = 61
~Point2D(), used_count = 60
~Point2D(), used_count = 59
~Point2D(), used_count = 58
~Point2D(), used_count = 57
~Point2D(), used_count = 56
~Point2D(), used_count = 55
~Point2D(), used_count = 54
~Point2D(), used_count = 53
~Point2D(), used_count = 52
~Point2D(), used_count = 51
~Point2D(), used_count = 50
~Point2D(), used_count = 49
~Point2D(), used_count = 48
~Point2D(), used_count = 47
~Point2D(), used_count = 46
~Point2D(), used_count = 45
~Point2D(), used_count = 44
~Point2D(), used_count = 43
~Point2D(), used_count = 42
~Point2D(), used_count = 41
~Point2D(), used_count = 40
~Point2D(), used_count = 39
~Point2D(), used_count = 38
~Point2D(), used_count = 37
~Point2D(), used_count = 36
~Point2D(), used_count = 35
~Point2D(), used_count = 34
~Point2D(), used_count = 33
~Point2D(), used_count = 32
~Point2D(), used_count = 31
~Point2D(), used_count = 30
~Point2D(), used_count = 29
~Point2D(), used_count = 28
~Point2D(), used_count = 27
~Point2D(), used_count = 26
L(N)_F: (-1, 9)_R(A) ~Point2D(), used_count = 25

L(I)_N: (1, 8)_R(H) ~Point2D(), used_count = 24
L(E)_A: (15, 7)_R(B) ~Point2D(), used_count = 23

I: (-2, 5)_R(J) ~Point2D(), used_count = 22
L(K)_H: (7, 6)_R(G) ~Point2D(), used_count = 21
E: (10, -2)_R(M) ~Point2D(), used_count = 20
L(C)_B: (16, 2)_R(D) ~Point2D(), used_count = 19

J: (2, 3) ~Point2D(), used_count = 18
K: (4, 0) ~Point2D(), used_count = 17
G: (6, 4) ~Point2D(), used_count = 16
M: (9, -3) ~Point2D(), used_count = 15
C: (12, 1) ~Point2D(), used_count = 14
D: (14, -1) ~Point2D(), used_count = 13

Height: 5
~PSTMultiset()
~Point2D(), used_count = 12
~Point2D(), used_count = 11
~Point2D(), used_count = 10
~Point2D(), used_count = 9
~Point2D(), used_count = 8
~Point2D(), used_count = 7
~Point2D(), used_count = 6
~Point2D(), used_count = 5
~Point2D(), used_count = 4
~Point2D(), used_count = 3
~Point2D(), used_count = 2
~Point2D(), used_count = 1
~Point2D(), used_count = 0
```

From this result, It seems the PST tree has correctly built with the code. But I'm not sure if the code is efficiency. **If you had time and convenient, could you please check the code? I greatly appreciate for any suggestions and comments**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, thanks for your kind comment! This is not a homework. These days I'm learning the basic data structures and algorithms, so I'm trying to implement them. I eager to learn more about C++ and write elegant code and beautiful design and solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## About using underscores

Avoid starting identifiers with an underscore, or using double underscores. Some uses of underscores are reserved, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

If you really want to use some way to distinguish private and public member variables, consider prefixing using `m_` or adding a single underscore at the end.

## Useless overloads

I see you often have two overloads for member functions, such as:

```
Point2D& operator=(const Point2D& other) {...}
Point2D& operator=(Point2D& other) {...}
```

Unless you plan to modify `other`, there is no need for the second version.

## Make member functions `const` if they do not modify the object

You should mark functions themselves as `const` if they do not make any modifications. For example:

```
bool operator<(const Point2D& other) const {
    return (m_y < other.m_y) || (m_y == other.m_y && m_x < other.m_x);
}
```

## Your set is actually a map

Your class name is `PSTMultiset`, but instead of a set you actually implement a map from a `Point2D<E>` to a `std::string`. And your internal use of `std::multiset` can thus be replaced with `std::multimap`, and you then also no longer need to declare a `struct Element`:

```
template <typename E>
class PSTMultimap {
    std::multimap<Point2D<E>, std::string> m_points;

    class Node {
        ...
        Point2D<E> m_key;
        std::string m_value;
        ...
    };

    ...
};
```

Inside `Build()` you want to create a `std::multimap` with a custom comparison function to sort on the `x` coordinate first:

```
struct Point2DComparatorX {
    bool operator()(const Point2D<E>& l, const Point2D<E>& r) {
        return (l.m_x < r.m_x) || (l.m_x == r.m_x && l.m_y < r.m_y);
    }
};

Node* Build(Node* parent, std::multimap<Point2D<E>, std::string>& points) {
    ...
    std::multimap<Point2D<E>, std::string, Point2DComparatorX> remainPoints;
    ...
};
```

## Consider not hardcoding the use of `Point2D` inside your PST

The only thing `PSTMultimap` needs to know about the type of keys is how to order them in two ways. It doesn't need to know you are sorting two-dimensional points. So it might be nicer if you could do something like:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare1 = std::less<>, typename Compare2 = std::less<>>
class PSTMultimap {
    std::multimap<Key, Value, Compare1> m_points;
public:
    PSTMultimap(Key keys[], Value values[], int size) ...

    class Node {
        ...
        Key m_key;
        Value m_value;
        ...
    };

    Node* Build(Node* parent, std::multimap<Key, Value>& points) {
       ...
       std::multimap<Key, Value, Compare2> remainPoints;
       ...
    }
    
    ...
};
```

And then let the caller worry about providing the right comparison functions:

```
std::string names[] = {"A", "B", ...};
Point2D<int> points[] = {{15, 7}, {16, 2}, ...};
int size = ...;

template<typename E>
struct Point2DComparatorX {
    bool operator()(const Point2D<E>& l, const Point2D<E>& r) {
        return (l.m_x < r.m_x) || (l.m_x == r.m_x && l.m_y < r.m_y);
    }
};

PSTMultimap<Point2D<int>, std::string, std::less<Point2D>, Point2DComparatorX<int>> t(names, points, size);
```

## Alternative constructors

Your constructor requires you to store the keys and values in two arrays. But what if you have the information in a different container? It might make sense to provide a constructor that takes two iterators to key/value `std::pair`s, like so:

```
template<typename Iterator>
PSTMultimap(const Iterator &begin, const Iterator &end) {
    for (Iterator it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        m_points[it->first] = it->second;
    }
}
```

And then use it, for example, like so:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Point2D<int>, std::string>> points = {
    {{15, 7}, "A"},
    {{16, 2}, "B"},
    ...
};

PSTMultimap<...> t(points.begin(), points.end());
```

## Consider allowing points to be added and removed from an existing PST

Just like regular STL contains, it would be nice to be able to `insert()` and `erase()` elements. Even better would be to make it look like a regular STL container.

## Make `Build()` automatic

I understand that you want to be able to print the situation before and after ordering the elements, but in production use, you don't need that, and it is much nicer if your class builds the PST automatically without having to manually call `Build()`.

Also, this will remove the need to temporarily store all the elements in a `std::multimap<>` member variable until `Build()` is called.

## Use `std::unique_ptr` to manage memory

Instead of having raw pointer variables and calling `new` and `delete` manually, consider using [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Use this for `PSTMultimap`'s `root` and `Node`'s `left` and `right` member variables.

## Improving efficiency

A major issue with your code is that you build a lot of temporary maps, and even do some unnecessary sorting. When building the PST, what you want to do at each recursive step is:

1. Get the max element using `Compare1`, this becomes the root.
2. Sort the remaining elements using `Compare2`.
3. Split the remaining elements in two, recurse each half, and add those as children.
4. Return the root.

Consider storing all the elements in a `std::vector` instead, and for each call to `Build()`, give it the `begin` and `end` position in this vector to use. Then the above steps become more concretely:

1. Use [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) using `Compare1` on the given range, then `std::swap()` it to the start of the range. Alternatively, you could use [`std::partial_sort(begin, begin + 1, end)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).
2. Use [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) from `begin + 1` to `end` using `Compare2`.
3. Find the midpoint, and recurse each half (`being + 1` to `mid_iter` and `mid_iter` to `end`)

So there's just one vector throughout the whole building process, of which smaller and smaller parts get sorted, without needing to allocate more and more maps. It also avoids full sorts just to get the maximum element.

Comment: `h3` (`###`) weight is fairly enough emphasis for section titles (and saves some vertical space). Good c++ reviews from your side otherwise

Comment: I greatly appreciate for your so detail answer! So many valuable suggestions and improvements! The most important I learnt from your answer is the valuable design experience using `C++`! I think I'm still in the kindergarden of `C++`.

Comment: 1. For the naming of private variables within the class, I'll follow your kind suggestion by using `m_`.

Comment: 2. For the useless copy constructor, I'll remove that. In fact another expert also suggest me this. I forgot to remove that overload.

Comment: 3. For the usage of `const`, I'll do more exercises. In fact, I encountered some `const`-related compiler errors before. I remembered that when I remove the `const` after the function, the errors were solved. I think I should do more study for the `const`.

Comment: 4. using `multiset` or `multimap`? I think I didn't have much opinion. In general, I think the `set` is suitable for no duplicate items, and the `map` is suitable for quick find usage. With my limited understanding of `set` and `map`, it seems the `set` is just a `subset` of the `map`. When equipping with some carefully designed hash functions and comparators, the `map` can be used as a `set`. I think the hash function and the comparators used in a `map` is the most important thing. But I didn't have much practical experiences.

Comment: 5. Thanks for your suggestion of designing the PST for general purpose. That would be much better. In fact, I didn't have these thoughts when I faced this new problems. This means a lot to me. I should do more practice!

Comment: 6. For the suggestion of `alternative constructors`, your solution is much smarter than that in my code. I didn't have the practical experience using the iterator for constructor. This is novel for me.

Comment: 7. For the `insert()` and `erase()` like other `STL` containers, I also want to add these operations. In fact, those operations are described in another note, http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs252/misc/resources/lectures/pdf/notes18.pdf, where the red-black tree is used for the basic data structure of PST. Currently that is difficult to me.

Comment: 8. For the automatically `Build` suggestion, yeah, understood. In the second note, http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs252/misc/resources/lectures/pdf/notes18.pdf, the PST will be constructed similar as a heap and the new elements will be inserted dynamically. This mechanism is more general and productive.

Comment: 9. For the `std::unique_ptr` suggestion, I'll try that. In fact, I'm not familiar with the new memory management, like the `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`. With my limited understanding of these new features, they implemented the strategy like the garbage-collection (GC)? So we don't need to manage the memory. Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but I don't know why I'm always prone to reject to use `*_ptr`, I always want to know when the objects are constructed and when they are destroyed. That's why I always add a `used_count` into the class definition. Despite this, I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: 10. Your last valuable suggestion of `improving efficienty` is my initial expectation when I post this question. In fact, I have the same concerns, in the original code, I used the `multiset`. Now I think that is truly unnecessary. With your suggested `vector`, the thing is getting more simpler and more elegant. You are an expert, thanks a lot for your so many valuable suggestions! So many words!

Comment: @mining Good luck with improving your class and your C++ skills, I'm glad you find the review helpful! About `set` and `map`: there really is no difference except `map` stores keys and values, whereas `set` only stores keys. As for `unique_ptr`: it is not garbage collected, it uses [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). But `shared_ptr` can be considered garbage collecting, although a simple form using reference counting.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, very grateful for your kind suggestions and detail explainations, which is very helpful and valuable! Thank you!